# Oracle ORA-01403: No Data Found while doing a JOIN with OPENQUERY on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

Here's a real head scracther (at least for me)

I'm running a query let's say it's:

```
SELECT number FROM equipment e
left outer join OPENQUERY(ORACLESERVER, 'SELECT num FROM equip_nums WHERE MODEL_NO = ''FOOBAR''') ora
ON e.number = ora.num
WHERE num IS NULL
      AND remove = 'no' 
      AND used = 'yes'
      AND model = 'FOOBAR'
```

This query is run for a number of models, about 50 of them. It works FINE for 47 of those models. But then it fails giving the following error:

```
    OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORACLESERVER" returned message "ORA-01403: no data found".
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORACLESERVER".
```

Now, I know what you're thinking.. "The query in the OPENQUERY is coming back empty, you need to handle that!" And while I agree that case should be handled.. The problem is that that query shouldn't be coming back empty! If I run this query from the same server

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLESERVER, 'SELECT num FROM equip_nums WHERE MODEL_NO = ''FOOBAR''')
```

I pull back about 1100 rows. So I feel like there should be data there for the join.

Can anyone shed ANY light on this? I'm really baffled here...

Comment: I find it odd that your query works at all since both tables have the field num and you didn't alias it in the where clause.

Comment: You could try pulling the data from the openquery into a temp table and then joining on that

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but since it took me some time figuring this and to save the next who might face the same issue, here is what I found:

Linked Server was probably created using Oracle Provider for OLE DB.
There is an Oracle **Bug 12861185** and **Doc ID 1462403.1** stating that joining data with an openquery set might result to `No data found` or `Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider ...`.

Solution provided is

1. Use the Oracle ODBC Driver.

If you have access to the ADO generated code than you have the following options:

1. Use CursorType of adOpenStatic, instead of adOpenForwardOnly.
2. Use CursorType of adOpenStatic, instead of adOpenForwardOnly.
3. Use CursorLocation of adUseClient (Microsoft's Cursor Library) instead of adUseServer (Oracle's Cursor Library) - which changes the default CursorType to adOpenStatic.
4. Increase the fetchsize to the value of the total number or rows.

It might be easier though to have the data fetched to a local table and then joining as already answered.